# Don't show a Colum if the condition is true once. In SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the problem that I want to only list Colums that have no entry for a specific value.
In this database I do have multiple persons with multiple percentages. If one person was ever listed for having 0.07 it is not allowed to show again for any other values. For Example by doing "WHERE percent IS NOT 0.07", "Stein, Peter" will still be listed at 0.16 percent but he should never be listed again.

[Image of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wzyt.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant record and not column, selecting dynamic column list is more difficult, but if you only wanted records of people that doesn't has a record with a specific value, you can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.name = s.name and s.prozent = 0.07)
```

This will select all records from your table, where there isn't a record exists with the same name and a percentage of 0.07